# I can't resize my root partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, root

I was running out of space from my `/` partition so I removed some space from the `/home` but I can't increase my `/` partition I've tried with gparted from a installation media, and tried from Windows 10 because I use dual boot. Here is what happened, I have some space that isn't allocated and the `/` partition:

[image: Screenshot of GParted showing partitions]

and what happens

[image: Screenshot of GParted resize partition dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't work on partitions that are currently mounted.**

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** the entire nvme0n1p9 partition all the way to the right
- **resize** the right side of nvme0n1p8 all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon

Answer (score 1):

Use "Partition | Resize/Move" menu option to move the home partition to the unused space then resize the root partition to the adjacent unused space. Search online for "gparted move partition to the right" to get details if needed.

Comment: Can't work on partitions that are currently mounted.